# Request must accept JSON in response

Tags: entries, cp-dashboard

I am getting error message while loading entries from dashboard. Please see attached screenshot -
[image]

While looking into browser console, I found the error message `Request must accept JSON in response` (using Craft v3.1.18)

Answer (score 1):

That means your server/browser isn't setting the proper `application/json` accept header for AJAX requests.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Brad. Over different browsers / locations, we are getting the same issue. I contacted to hosting provider and they said developer to analyse problem. Now, I am clueless for the next step :(

Comment: Any updates on resolving this issue? It's happening to a client's site now, with Craft 3 and Nginx.